# MAGENTO How do I view all products in a Root Category INCLUDING those within it’s subcategory

Tags: magento, categories, product

I really need some help with this. In the Admin Panel I select ‘Manage Category’. I click on a Root Category and select the ‘Category Products’ tab, hoping to view all of the products that are contained in that Root Category INCLUDING those that are assigned to the Root Category’s Sub Categories. Unfortunately, that is not what happens. Instead, I only get to see the products that are assigned specifically to that Root Category, which in my case is usually none.

I found what I thought was the solution to this problem but this just doesn’t seem to work for me at all. This is the solution that I found that seems to work for others but so far, not for me.

*Go to Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> “Select Category” -> Display Settings -> Is Anchor = “Yes”*

*Then:
Admin -> System -> Index Management -> “Select All” -> “Reindex data” -> “Submit”*

If anybody has any alternative suggestions OR a suggestion as to why the above doesn’t work for me, I’d be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is nothing to do with the category settings. The method you have described does not help in this case. This is down to product settings. When you assigned the product at the Category section (at left sidebar) you need to tick parent category as well as it's sub-category to appear in Category Products in Manage categories. Then, you can control appearance at the front end via Is Anchor.